# angular 2, ngFor not working with error in console

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to follow a tutorial. This is a simple page which displays courses. I'm getting below error in console. Angular 2 dependency is "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7". I have tried using '#' in stead of 'let'.

Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property 
    ("{{title}}
      
         ]*ngFor="let course for courses">
          {{course}}

Module course.components.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesService} from './courses.service';

@Component({    selector:'courses',
    template:`<h1>Courses</h1>
          {{title}}
          <ul>
             <li *ngFor="let course for courses">
          {{course}}
         </li>
          </ul>
          `,
        providers:[CoursesService]
    })
export class CoursesComponent
{
   title="The title of courses page";
   courses;

   constructor(coursesService:CoursesService)
   {
     this.courses = coursesService.getCourses();
   }
} 

Module course.service.ts
export class CoursesService
{
   getCourses():string[]
   {
     return ["Course1","Course2","Course3"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `for` in front of courses:

```
<li *ngFor="let course of courses">
```

and import your service file correctly.

Also I have created a plunker for you at: http://plnkr.co/edit/ldpRkJLR89e6aF4McdQD?p=preview

Hope this help!

Comment: You mean I have used 'for' instead of using 'of' infront of courses. Thank you.. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 has a final release several weeks ago and you should update to this final version to catch the change and notes that in 2.0.0.beta.7 the `#` is not yet deprecated